# Scala "fluent" style programming

Tags: scala, types, fluent, method-chaining

I'm learning Scala from the book "Scala for the Impatient". One section in the book illustrates the "fluent" style of programming with the following code snippet:

```
object Title

class Document {
  private var useNextArgAs: Any = null
  def set(obj: Title.type): this.type = { useNextArgAs = obj; this }
  def to(arg: String) = if (useNextArgAs == Title) title = arg; else ...
}
```

The author then makes the following method call:

```
book set Title to "Scala for the Impatient"
```

Some questions here:

1. Why is `useNextArgAs` type `Any`? The only type that's used in the example for `useNextArgAs` is a `Title`. Can you show a use case for using `Any` instead of `Title`?
2. Method `set` returns `this` but the return type is `this.type`, not `Document`? Isn't `this` supposed to be the instance?
3. In method `to`, `title = arg` refers to non-existent var `title`? Where did it come from?

Comment: The book is focused on Scala and shows such example with mutable `var` and `Any` type without warning?

Comment: @cchantep "for the Impatient" is a clue :) From amazon reviews `A java programmer after reading this book will only write scala in a java style of programming. That's not what we want.
We need developers who can think and program in scala way.`

Comment: I disagree with whoever wrote that review. I've 3 books on Scala, "Scala for the Impatient", "Learning Scala" and "Programming in Scala" and IMHO, "Impatient..." is the best of the bunch. It has the requisite depth but doesn't put you to sleep. Perhaps the reviewer didn't work the exercises and that's where they missed the point. The exercises are as important as the lessons because each question makes you think. I see that "the scala way" is touted too loosely by too many people without an explanation of what it means to them, if anything at all. Disclaimer: I'm not paid by the author.

Answer (score 1):

A possible (not entirely correct) implementation for this excercise from the book can be found (**Spoiler Alert!**) in [github](https://github.com/calinburloiu/Scala-for-the-Impatient--Exercises/blob/master/src/exercises/c18_advanced_types/Exer03.scala)

The chapter 18 where this example comes from is labeled as "Senior Lib Designer" difficulty level. At this level a person should be well aware of re-use and extensibility issues, and consequences of mutable state in scala. **This is definetely not a technic for beginners.**

To OP's questions:

1) *Why is useNextArgAs type Any?* --- to make it support arbitrary attribute types in Document sub-classes. `Document` is not declared `final`

2) *Method set returns this but the return type is this.type* --- see Alvin Alexander's article below (you probably have the explanation in "Scala for the Impatient")

> explicitly setting `this.type` as the return type of your set* methods
>   ensures that the fluent style will continue to work in your subclasses

consider the following extension and play around with `set()` and `to()` return type and value

```
class Book extends Document {
  def bind :this.type = {/*do something*/; this}
}

val book = new Book
(book set Title to "Scala for the Impatient").bind
```

3) *non-existent var title* --- it is a mutable field in Document, just missing in the code snippet provided

Some extra reading on the subject:

- http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-fluent-style-programming-methods-in-scala
- http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html

Comment: 2) Let me put the question differently. I understand the reason behind return type `this.type`, that's explained in the book as well. What I was asking is that the return type is specified as `this.type` but `this` is returned. I was expecting `this.type` to be returned instead.

Comment: you need to return `this` for chaining, but you cannot use just `this` as a type. if you hardcode the type to concrete Class (`Document` in this case) or let compiler infer it (`Document` in this case) - you won't be able to chain methods on subclasses without explicit typecasting. so `this.type` is the only working option.